# Time complexity of Metropolis-Hastings and potential speed-up?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, dimensionality-reduction, metropolis-hastings, time-complexity

The MH algorithm essentially involves generating a sample destination state from a proposal distribution, computing the acceptance probability as a function of that sample, and checking whether a uniform random variable is above the acceptance probability to determine whether to move to the new state or not.

- What is the time complexity of each step? Is it the case that each step in this algorithm is really fast, and so MH is time-bottlenecked by the mixing time it takes for the distribution to converge?
- How does the time complexity depend on the dimension of the data in the underlying joint distribution being approximated in the first place (recall MH seeks to provide samples drawn from a PDF approximating some target distribution/PDF)?
- For the exponential family, the acceptance probability of a proposed state $x_{m+1}$ is given by $$p(x_{m+1}=x' \mid x_m)=\min \left[1, \frac{\exp \left\{\eta \cdot T(x')\right\} Q(x_m \mid x')}{\exp \{\eta \cdot T(x_m)\} Q(x' \mid x_m)}\right]$$

where both exponentials contain a dot product involving the sufficient statistic. Since approximate isometries are guaranteed to exist for data sets (by JL Lemma), why can't we always project data down into a much lower dimension such that all data points have the same pairwise dot products, then compute the acceptance probability/run M-H with the lower dimensional data points, if the only thing we use about the data points are their dot products with other data points?

Answer (score 1):

The time-complexity of a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm depends on the complexity of the target distribution. In Bayesian statistics where the target is a function of a sample of $n$ observations, computing the target distribution at a new value [proposed state] is generally of order $\text{O}(n)$ if there is no sufficient statistic (i.e., outside exponential families). The dimension $d$ of the state space also impacts the computation time at each step.

Dimension also matters in the [number of steps needed to achieve
stationarity](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucakabe/papers/QMCMC_09.pdf), whose order $\text{O}(d^\alpha)$ will increase with $d$.